# What does "S-ILS" signify in an FAA NOTAM?

Tags: faa-regulations, instrument-procedures, notam

Consider this NOTAM for LAX from the [current list](https://pilotweb.nas.faa.gov/PilotWeb/notamRetrievalByICAOAction.do?method=displayByICAOs&reportType=RAW&formatType=DOMESTIC&retrieveLocId=LAX&actionType=notamRetrievalByICAOs):

> FDC 5/0341 LAX IAP LOS ANGELES INTL LOS ANGELES CA. ILS OR LOC RWY 25L AMDT 12C... S-ILS 25L DA 395/ HAT 291 ALL CATS VISIBILITY ALL CATS RVR 2200. ADD NOTE FOR INOPERATIVE ALSF-2 INCREASE S-ILS 25L VISIBILITY ALL CATS TO RVR 4500. EXCEPT WHEN ADVISED BY ATC THAT EQUIPMENT IS DOWN. CONSTRUCTION EQUIPMENT 178 MSL BEGINNING 1399 FEET NORTHEAST OF RWY 25L. 1502052152-1508042152EST

What does `S-ILS25L` signify, how is it different than just `ILS25L`, and where can I find the source document?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `S` is for the straight-in portion of that approach (this is explained in the Abbreviations section of the Terminal Procedures Publication ([See here](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/digital_products/dtpp/search/) - it's in the Abbreviations section of "Legends and General Information" at the bottom).  In this case the decision altitudes, height above thresholds, and weather minimums have changed.

[Check out the approach plate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7szFM.png) and at the bottom you'll see S-ILS 15, S-LOC/DME 15, CIRCLING, etc.

Comment: I appreciate the government source, thanks.